# Colorscale in plotly()

Tags: r, colors, plotly, colorbrewer

I am tring to create `plotly` bar plot with scalling colors.
I have found out how to adjust color scaling by variable, but don't know how to choose another pallet. I would like to use `RBrewerPallet` for example.
Here is an example.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(total = sum(Wind)) %>%
plot_ly(x = ~Month,
        y = ~total, 
        type = 'bar',
        marker = list(
          color = ~total
        ))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to specify the color scale for bar charts in plotly:

```
  library(plotly)
  library(dplyr)
  airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(total = sum(Wind)) %>%
    plot_ly(x = ~Month,
            y = ~total, 
            type = 'bar',
            marker = list(
              color = ~total,
              colorscale='Blues'
            ))
```

[image]

I know of these palletes: "Blackbody", "Bluered", "Blues", "Earth", "Electric",  "Greens",  "Greys", "Hot",  "Jet",  "Picnic",  "Portland", "Rainbow", "RdBu", "Reds", "Viridis", "YlGnBu", "YlOrRd".

if not enough you can manually specify:

`marker = list(color = c('rgba(204,204,204,1)', 'rgba(222,45,38,0.8)',
                                'rgba(204,204,204,1)', 'rgba(204,204,204,1)',
                                'rgba(204,204,204,1)')`